# Django Resuable QuerySet

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet in a view like the following. I would like to be able to use the same query in other views, but I don't want to have to copy and paste the code. This also feels like I would be violating the DRY principal.

If I would like to modify the query at a later date, I would have to change it in all my views, which clearly isn't ideal. Is there a class I should create or a method in my model which would let me call this from many different views? Are there any best practices concerning this?

`tasks = Task.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by('-created_at', 'is_complete')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put common queries in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541780/where-to-put-common-queries-in-django)

Answer (score 4):

One of the solutions would be to create a classmethod on the model or extending model's manager.

`from django.db import models`

1. Adding classmethod

   ```
   class MyModel(models.Model):
       @classmethod
       def get_user_tasks(cls, user):
           return cls.objects.filter(...).order_by(...)
   ```
2. Overriding manager

   ```
   class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
       def get_user_tasks(self, user):
           return self.filter(...).order_by(...)

   class MyModel(models.Model):
       objects = MyModelManager()

   # and in the view...
   queryset = MyModel.objects.get_user_tasks(request.user)
   ```

Comment: Of these, the Manager method is the more Django-nic.